# Python: Concatenate two strings for getting a variable from a class

Tags: python, class

I have a Python class , having some variables. The definition of the class is as follows:

```
class student:
    def __init__(self,name,rollno,DOB,branch):
       self.name=name
       self.rollno=rollno
       self.DOB=DOB
       self.branch=branch
       self.books=[]
       self.fines=[]
```

I am **adding new attributes** for a student , and need to store the corresponding values as well (for future use). This is done using the setattr method, and works fine.

Code snippet:

```
setattr(student,"date_of_join",date())
```

Now I am approaching the problem as, if the user adds a new attribute (say, "**date_of_join**"), then I update a list (**studattr**), initially containing **["name","rollno",DOB","branch","books","fines"]**  to update the list of attributes. This means that the updated list will also have "date_of_join" now appended to it.

Now if I want to **access this list of attributes of a student Instance**, then how do I do it? ( Since the records are dynamically updated, and let us suppose I have to access x.date_of_join, then how do I join the two strings? Is there anything similar to python's os.path.join, or rather linux's system call, (merging two strings)? )

Problem:

```
for attribute in studattr:
    print attribute,x.attribute

{ This throws an Exception since the instance x has no variable or method named "attribute")
```

PS: I tried using inspect,inspect.getmembers(x) as well as dirs(x), vars(x) ,(mentioned on stackoverflow), but it only gives me a list of variables/methods in main class body and not in **init**.

Comment: I guess you need `getattr`: `getattr(x, attribute)`

Comment: Instead of using an object instance on which you set attributes, isn't a normal dictionary a better fit for what you're trying to do?

Comment: If you're getting a list of variables/methods in the main class body, then you're not running `dir` on the instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to access dynamic attributes:

```
for attr in student.studattr:
    print attr, getattr(student, attr)
```

or use `vars()` will give you a dictionary of current attributes on a student:

```
for attr, value in vars(student).iteritems():
    print attr, value
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!